# How to load save Preferences from one button to another

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences

I am exploring android and I am working on one of the tasks where I have a 2 Edit text fields and two buttons.

1st EditText is to enter Name
2nd EditText is to enter Phone Number

1st Button is to save Name and Phone Number entered.
2nd Button is to call the Phone Number entered in the Edit text box.

I have saved the details using the following Code

```
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("phoneNumber",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putString("phoneNumber",number1.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("savename", name.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved Contact",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This is My call button which uses the saved Phone Number and call when clicked on call.

```
 callBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String uri = "tel:" + number.getText().toString();
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));

                startActivity(callIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your call has failed...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I use the saved Phone Number in callBtn function? Can you Please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the save button, you want to create a `SharedPreferences.Editor` instance.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

Then we use the editor's methods to put a string (The name) and an int (The phone number) into the shared preferences.

```
editor.putString ("name", editText1.getText().toString()).apply();//remember to call apply()!
editor.putInt ("phoneNumber", Integer.parseInt (editText2.getText().toString())).apply();
```

And to recieve the shared preferences, create a `SharedPreference` instance.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And use `getString` and `getInt` to get the corresponding stuff.

```
prefs.getString ("name", "");
prefs.getInt ("phoneNumber", 0);
```

The second parameter is the default value. If it can't find the preference with the keys, it would return the default value. So if the user doesn't save the name and phone no., it would use "" and 0, but I think you should use a better default value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question with the code I have written. Can you please tell me if I am doing it right?

Comment: Yes that's how you do it! @G'one'